# Mean Stack API calls are very slow

Tags: node.js, angular, apache, express, mean-stack

We build a MEAN stack application, everything is proper at the client side but on the server-side, the API requests and responses are very slow.

Ex. If there was a request made from angular the request takes 6-8 seconds to reach the server-side.

This happened both in localhost and hosted server

is there any configuration that needs to be made to make the request and response fast?

We are using node 12, angular 8 and apache

Comment: first open your FE app and look through the devtools network tab. find any of your requests and check what exactly takes most of the time. I expect "Waiting (TTFB)" to take most of the time, but there could be other problems. if TTFB was the major piece - indeed it takes too long for the server to execute its code and you should be looking for problem there. there are many utils that allow to measure pieces of code evaluation time for example `process.hrtime()`. use it to find bottleneck in the code

Answer (score 0):

Here are something i do to make my application faster.

**Angular**

- Apply lazy loading in angular for small bundles and code splitting.
- Use production builds.

**Node**

- Compress my response using compression by express.
- Use lean() if you are using mongoose to convert mongoose objects into plain javascript objects (Note: lean will disable mongoose functions like save remove etc).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, am already doing all the points you have mentioned. my problem is that the requests angular make to node server that takes time.

Comment: This are the general steps of optimisation. However your question is very wide and it is hard to answer the question without looking at the code.